# how to write a text file in python executing it from PHP

Tags: php, python, file, text, file-handling

I want to write a simple text file using Python, calling that python code from a PHP script. i have written a simple python code which writes a text file and prints the result in console. its working fine. when i call it from a php, the output is coming in PHP,but unfortunately the output is not writing in the text file. Here is the Python code-

```
a = 2;
b = 3;
c = a + b;
f = open('result.txt', 'wb');
f.write(str(c));
f.close(); 
print "Value of c is ", c;
```

The execution statement in php is-

```
$result= exec("C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda\python C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda\hello.py");
echo "<br> $result";
```

result is printing in html.no problem. but the file is not working. any suggestions?

Comment: Didn't got fille is not working???

Comment: the output is not coming in the text file when i execute it from a php file